# ActiveSheet.Range AutoFilter RGB Is Slow

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a macro in Excel VBA and one of the steps within it is performing an AutoFilter on the ActiveSheet range, filter based on color.  This step seems quite time consuming and I am wondering if there might be a quicker way to filter my data?  Is filtering on color usually slower?  here's a sample of the code that I am using:

```
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$100000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255 _
    , 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
Rows("2:100000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: What does "quite time consuming" mean? Do you really need to go to row 100k?

Comment: @SJR, no, you have a point there.  I did not originally write this code.  I think the author was trying to make sure they captured all records in the macro.  They data set I was running had approx 32K rows

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. Define the last row of data and don't select. I'm not sure it will make a huge difference but see how it goes.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim r As Long

r = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AB$" & r)
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End With

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    rng.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = 0
End Sub
```